# Return multiple resultset from stored procedure in Single DataTable object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have Stored Procedure which returns Multiple tables as ResultSet. I Stored it in DataTable and Pass that DataTable Object to Another Form Which Print Tables In MY Web Page.
My Question is How Can i Stored Multiple ResultSet Returned from Stored Procedure into SINGLE DataTable Object Which I Can return to another function.

```
    public static DataTable[] getGraphData(Int32 type)
{
    SqlConnection oConn = null;
    DataSet dsReturn = null;
    DataTable[] dtReturn=new DataTable[2];
    try
    {
        getConnection(ref oConn, 1);

        using (SqlStoredProcedure sspObj = new SqlStoredProcedure("dbo.usp_getGraphData", oConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            sspObj.AddParameterWithValue("@Type", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, type);
            dsReturn = sspObj.ExecuteDataSet();
            dtReturn[0] = dsReturn.Tables[0];
            dtReturn[1] = dsReturn.Tables[1];
            dtReturn[2] = dsReturn.Tables[2];
            sspObj.Dispose();
        }
        closeConnection(ref oConn);
    }
    catch (Exception xObj)
    {
        //dtReturn[] = new DataTable();
    }
    return dtReturn;
}
```

Function Which Takes the all three DataTables

```
DataTable dtOutput = Generix.getGraphData(type);
```

How to get Each DataTable From Here ? Means 0th Element to dtOutput1 ,  1st Element to dtOutput2.....Like wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a dataset as podiluska mentioned, and then access the DataSet.Tables property to gets your three table one by one.

If the three table structure is difderent does not make sense to foece them into a table. For this the DataSet is the better way. It is kind of collection of your table.

EDIT for the question about the DataTable[]:

```
DataTable[] dtOutputs = Generix.getGraphData(type); 
//dtReturn[0]
DataTable dtOutput0 = dtOutputs[0];
//dtReturn[1]
DataTable dtOutput1 = dtOutputs[1];
//dtReturn[2]
DataTable dtOutput2 = dtOutputs[2];
```

Or if you need not only reference those table, but copy them, you can use .Copy() like:

```
//dtReturn[0]
DataTable dtOutput1 = dtOutputs[1].Copy;
```

I still think that the best way would be returning a DataSet by the query (it doesn't make sense to make a DataTable query from that.)

```
public static DataSet getGraphData(Int32 type)
{
    SqlConnection oConn = null;
    DataSet dsReturn = null;
    try
    {
        getConnection(ref oConn, 1);

        using (SqlStoredProcedure sspObj = new SqlStoredProcedure("dbo.usp_getGraphData", oConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            sspObj.AddParameterWithValue("@Type", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, type);
            dsReturn = sspObj.ExecuteDataSet();
            //You don't need Dispose() - because the using will do that on sspObj
        }

        closeConnection(ref oConn);
    }
    catch (Exception xObj)
    {
        dsReturn = new DataSet("Empty");
    }
    return dsReturn ;
}
```

And calling the method like this:

```
 DataSet dsOutput = Generix.getGraphData(type);

    //Simply a reference or Copy() the DataSet's tables:
    DataTable dtOutput0 = dsOutput.Tables[0];
    DataTable dtOutput1 = dsOutput.Tables[1];
    DataTable dtOutput2 = dsOutput.Tables[2];
```

Comment: Go through Edit. Used DataSet Now Want to Extract Each DataTable From Array

Comment: Should be 
DataTable[] dtOutputs = Generix.getGraphData(type); 
DataTable dtOutput1 = dtOutputs[0]; 

Or if you need not just the reference but a new dataTable with the same values then dtOutput[0].Copy()

If not this is what you are looking for then sorry, but I don't understand what you need exactly.

Comment: Will this statement return dtReturn; will return all elements i.e. 0,1,2 ??

Comment: dtOutputs will be dtReturn with all three elements. The second line dtOutput1 would be the dtRaturn0, you should apply the same logic for dtOutput2 and dtOutput3. So you should repeat the second line three times to get those three table into different table. But I don't see then the efficiency of a DataTable[] instead of DataSet, because you can get a table from a dataset like: ds.Tables[0], or ds.Tables[1].

Answer (score 0):

Use a union in your stored procedure to join the result sets together

ie:

```
SELECT * from yourtable WHERE name='bob'
UNION ALL
SELECT * from yourtable WHERE name='jane'
```

If you want to return your multiple tables into a single object, you can use a `DataSet` (which contains multiple tables) instead of a `DataTable`. You populate it in the same way.

eg:

```
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
new SqlAdapter(command).Fill (dst);
```

Comment: I dont have Matching Column No/Datatype in My Stored Procedure.

Comment: Then what do you want your single table to look like?

Comment: It's Multiple Table With Different Column And DataType.I want to return it as 3 Different DataTables.